# Front end wp_editor not rendering audio/video links

Tags: media, wp-editor, embed

I have an editor on the front end of a website using wp_editor. It mostly works as expected; very similar to the admin side editor. However, when I enter an audio or video link, the players are not rendered as they are on the admin side. For example, inputting:-

```
http://chromafunk.com/bucket/ring.mp3
```

...on the admin side will immediately render to the audio player. On my public side wp_editor, it remains as a URL string.

There are obviously some filters/scripts on the admin side that render these URLs that are not available as standard from the public facing side. Is it possible to get a public side wp_editor to behave exactly like the admin side editor? Its kind of pointless having front end editing if I lose a chunk of functionality from the admin side editor.

Im using my own custom plugin to launch the editor. Im using the following:-

```
function create_tinymce() {
    $settings = array(
        'media_buttons' => true,
        'drag_drop_upload' => false,
        'wpautop' => true,
        );
    wp_editor("", "my-editor", $settings);
}
```

Im then hooking the above function using:-

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'create_tinymce', 0 );
```

Comment: How are you adding it to the frontend? Are you using a plugin? If not can you show us some of your code?

Comment: Thanks Fencer. Ive appended my OP with some code examples.

Comment: There are 2 trac tickets regarding the oEmbed functionality outside of post/page edit screens [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33917) and [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34115). It looks like it is on the radar but won't appear until an unspecified future release.

Answer (score 2):

I've been fighting this for a while on a series of themes I make that provide a front end content creation interface not requiring a WP account. For the last two years I have said "trust me, URLs will embed".

Those old tickets are dormant, but I just have found a solution here
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/287623

For the template that renders the page you are using for your form, you need to add an enqueue statement.

This is some partial code on a site where auto embeds are not working on an editor added `via wp_editor()`

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_truwriter_scripts');

function add_truwriter_scripts() {  

    // set up main styles
    $parent_style = 'radcliffe_style'; 

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );



if ( is_page('write') ) { // use on just our form page

    // Get Embed functionality in rich text editor
    // h/t https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/287623
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mce-view' );
   :
   :
   // unrelated code follows
```

Comment: Does this still work?

Comment: It only worked when my code was secretly logging in as an author. My hunch is it's a problem caling admin-ajax.php Got no answer here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/no-media-embeds-for-non-loggedin-users-on-front-end-form/